# What happens when RestTemplate gets a null response from spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to know what's going on when a spring server returns a null object (instead of an "empty" object), on the client side. Does it raise an exception ? or simply mark it as `null` too ?

Client code :

```
// Does it throw an exception or will I have obj==null or obj "empty" ?
MyDto obj = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyDto.class);
```

Server code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/urlpath", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public MyDto getObj() {
    return null;
}
```

I have simplified the code of course. The reason why I am asking here is that it takes a long time to turn on my debug server and to create a simple basic environment with all this with pom.xml etc (I am new to spring).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you annotate your handler method with `@ResponseBody`, Spring uses `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to generate the response body. It does this in its `handleReturnValue` method which is implemented as

```
@Override
public void handleReturnValue(Object returnValue, MethodParameter returnType,
        ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer, NativeWebRequest webRequest)
        throws IOException, HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {

    mavContainer.setRequestHandled(true);
    if (returnValue != null) {
        writeWithMessageConverters(returnValue, returnType, webRequest);
    }
}
```

So if the returned value is  `null`, nothing will be written to the body.

The `RestTemplate` will therefore try to deserialize a `MyDto` from an empty `String`. `RestTemplate` uses an `HttpMessageConvertExtractor` to deserialize the response. The `extractData` method is implemented as

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public T extractData(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    if (!hasMessageBody(response)) {
        return null;
    }
    MediaType contentType = getContentType(response);

    for (HttpMessageConverter<?> messageConverter : this.messageConverters) {
        if (messageConverter instanceof GenericHttpMessageConverter) {
            GenericHttpMessageConverter<?> genericMessageConverter = (GenericHttpMessageConverter<?>) messageConverter;
            if (genericMessageConverter.canRead(this.responseType, null, contentType)) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Reading [" + this.responseType + "] as \"" +
                            contentType + "\" using [" + messageConverter + "]");
                }
                return (T) genericMessageConverter.read(this.responseType, null, response);
            }
        }
        if (this.responseClass != null) {
            if (messageConverter.canRead(this.responseClass, contentType)) {
                if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    logger.debug("Reading [" + this.responseClass.getName() + "] as \"" +
                            contentType + "\" using [" + messageConverter + "]");
                }
                return (T) messageConverter.read((Class) this.responseClass, response);
            }
        }
    }
    throw new RestClientException(
            "Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [" +
                    this.responseType + "] and content type [" + contentType + "]");
}
```

In other words, if there is no body, it returns `null`.

So your `MyDto` object here

```
MyDto obj = restTemplate.getForObject(url, MyDto.class);
```

will be `null`.